# Ubuntu 19.04 on ASUS Zenbook UX333FN

Tags: 19.04

Has anyone tried booting a live usb on ASUS Zenbook UX333FN? The grub screen boot up, but after I select the option to try Ubuntu, I'm treated with black screen. Not sure if it's because of kernel 5.0. Previous version of Ubuntu boot fine. This also happens for other Ubuntu 19.04 flavour. I tested with Xubuntu and Ubuntu Budgie.

**Edit (20 Apr 2019)**

I tried with a few other options. Now I'm not sure if it's due to kernel 5.0 or something else. I installed Elementary OS 5.0 Juno and use UKUU to upgrade the kernel to 5.0.9, and it actually works. So I'm not sure what's the problem to be solved here...

Comment: It is already some time, maybe solved already, but still maybe an interesting question: did you check the microcode problem ? See https://petrnosek.cz/problem-pri-bootovani-jadra-asus-zenbook-ux362fa-vypnuti-zavadeni-mikrokodu/ or https://github.com/ShangChunLin/zenbook-issuse-with-ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue installing 19.04 on Asus Zenbook UX433 and am still having the same problem intermittently after installation. After trying a few things I managed to boot into the 'Try Ubuntu' screen and from there perform a successful installation. These are the steps I followed:

- Create a bootable USB drive using Rufus (I initially tried the installation with Unetbootin however this did not work)
- Disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot in the BIOS menu
- Boot into GRUB and select Try Ubuntu. This took a few attempts as I also got the black screen

After booting into Ubuntu using the Try Ubuntu method I was able to perform the installation however I am still getting the blank screen intermittently after trying to boot into Ubuntu from GRUB. What's strange is that the issue does not seem to be reproducible. Sometimes I am able to boot into Ubuntu after selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu. Other times I have to go into Advanced Options for Ubuntu and select the option to boot using Linux 5.0.

Comment: good to know it's not just me.

Comment: The following question describes the problem I was having - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144688/ubuntu-18-10-stuck-at-initialising-ramdisk-after-fresh-install-and-subsequent-up. I was able to resolve the issue using the workaround described in the Launchpad link.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my Asus zenbook UX333FN.

I made multiple try but I did not succed to install Ubuntu 19.04 with an usb live. I 
also try to upgrade from 18.04 but I had black screen at boot and I was not able to load any kernel image anymore.

So I install Ubuntu 18.04 and update the kernel to 5.0.9 with ukuu and everythings seems to work (sound too).

Comment: Ya, I actually just did the same. Have the same issue after upgrading to 19.04 from 18.04. 18.10 (upgraded from 18.04) with kernel 5.0.9 from ukuu is working fine actually.