# Ubuntu 18.10 stuck at initialising ramdisk after fresh install and subsequent update/`sudo apt upgrade`; Potential broken package

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates, suspend, 18.10

**Specs**

- Asus Zenbook 14 UX433FN (NVMe PCIe SSD)
- Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10 dual boot, Windows 10 working fine.

**Background**

Today my Ubuntu 18.10 suddenly gave me a "purple screen of death" after I closed my laptop lid (ie. it couldn't wake up from suspend).

After which, I forced shutdown and tried to reboot (both normally and with recovery mode), and both times it got stuck at 
`Loading initial ramdisk...`

**Quirky Behaviour**

After this I successfully reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10 using CD. **TWICE.**

Each time, after successfully installing graphics drivers and everything, Ubuntu automatically prompts me to do security updates etc. Before installing updates, I can use and boot into Ubuntu normally.

**BUT** after installing these updates successfully, and rebooting, I get stuck at `Loading initial ramdisk...` again.

**Update!**
After my third re-installation, I decided to do `sudo apt upgrade` from command line directly instead of the GUI as I did previously.

**I got the same error again!**

This hints at the possibility of a bug or broken package in the apt repository. As this is a fresh Ubuntu 18.10 install, this is extremely puzzling.

**Resolution attempts**

1. Use LiveCD as per
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure.
2. Update kernels before installing.
3. Replacing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.

Why is this so? Is there a bug in the update repositories somewhere?

I can use Ubuntu without updating of course, but this leaves my computer vulnerable to security issues. In the long-run, being afraid of updating the computer lest I get this same error is quite stupid.

**UPDATE:**

A bug report has been filed. Apparently I'm not the only one affected.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1829735

Apparently `acpi_osi=off` might work.

**Potential Fix:**

Apparently, this might be due to a known bug in Asus.

Check out bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

Several solutions might be found there.

Comment: @whoever posted yesterday but deleted their answer, why did u do so? You did mention helpful advise that while it might not have answered my question directly, was still good troubleshooting advice?

Comment: You can check my answer to https://askubuntu.com/a/1176658/456213. I fixed this problem on my Asus Zenbook 14 UX433FN.