# Blank screen after click option (Install Ubuntu, Try Ubuntu without Installing, etc.) on Ubuntu Installing Grub (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi

So I have a new laptop, an Asus Zenbook UX433fn. This laptop already has Windows 10 (home) installed and I want to change it to Ubuntu. I use flashdisk for the bootable (I use UUI). But I have a problem when trying to install Ubuntu 19.04. The problem is:

Screen goes blank (black screen) after click Install Ubuntu on Ubuntu Installing Grub.

I already tried this:

1. Click 'e' on grub, and replace quiet splash --- to nomodeset ---
2. Click 'e' on grub, and add nomodeset on front quiet splash ( it bcome: nomodeset quiet splash --- )
3. Click 'e' on grub, and add nomodeset on last quiet splash. ( it bcome:
   quiet splash nomodeset --- )
4. Disable fastboot option on BIOS
5. Disable secure boot on BIOS
6. Disable fastboot on windows setting (power options)

But no luck, still blank screen.

FYI this is my laptop spec:

- Intel Core I7 (8th Gen)
- Intel UHD 620 + Nvidia MX150 2GB DDR5
- etc.

Please help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an a bug in `microcode_ctl` . This is a package which contains both processor ‘microcode’ updates and a loader for such updates, for Intel processors.

There are three possible solutions for it.

1. You can add `dis_ucode_ldr` to the kernel parameters to boot into the kernel, and then make it persistent once in by adding it  to `/etc/default/grub` then update-grub.
2. You can boot using the above method once then roll back to a previous version of the microcode package and mark it down, using the following commands

`sudo apt install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1`

Then hold the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

3. You can update the bios to a version where this issue is fixed. Updating the BIOS is the most recommended and foolproof option in my opinion since it addresses the root cause of the problem. You can find instruction on how to update the BIOS below.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859/

All three solutions worked for me on ASUS Zenbook UX433FN, when I tried them once after the other. I hope it helps you out.

Comment: I can't describe how perfect and helpful this answer is, I wish I could give it a 100 upvotes.

Comment: I am glad my answer could help